# Showing Iterated Cosines are Equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_1: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define $f_{n+1}(x)$ by
$$
f_{n+1}(x)=\cos f_n(x)
$$
Show that $\{f_n\}$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence.

My Attempt: It is clear that $[0,1]$ is compact. It is clear $f_1$ is bounded, say by $M$ and that $f_n$ is bounded (by 1) so that $|f_n(x)| \leq \max \{M,1\}$ so that they are uniformly bounded. Moreover, $f_1(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (hence uniformly so) and as the composition of continuous functions are continuous, $f_n(x)$ is continuous (hence uniformly so) on $[0,1]$.

It only remains to show that the set $\{f_n(x)\}$ is equicontinuous. I have tried to do this several ways but have come up short. I can only think that as $f_1(x)$ is uniformly continuous, the $\delta$ produced by this should work, perhaps with a bit of alteration, for all the $f_n(x)$ but I don't see how to force the inequality
$$
|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq |f_1(x)-f_1(y)|
$$
or if it is even true. Any hints on showing the equicontinuity?

Comment: It is not clear that $[0,1]$ is compact. Heine and Borel deserve far more credit than you've given them.

Comment: @NoahOlander After ones first Real Analysis course, it usually considered trivial that any interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact - of course, via Heine-Borel.

Comment: Haha, if you say so. We have different definitions of trivial though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniform continuity of $f_1$ is enough since by the mean value theorem, $|\cos x-\cos y| \leq |x-y|$. So, $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq |f_1(x)-f_1(y)|$.

Comment: Thank you! I had thought of exactly this but somehow convinced myself that it wouldn't work as one couldn't guarantee $f_1(x)$ was differentiable. I needed to see someone else to suggest it for me to see that I was being asinine!